# Class definition problem

Tags: php, class

Can someone tell me why I cannot write a class as follows

```
<?php
class Foo 
{
?>
<?php
       function bar() {
           print "bar";
       }
}
?>
```

I think it's the same as

```
<?php
class Foo 
{
       function bar() {
           print "bar";
       }
}
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /home/beiju/beiju.info/testscripts/clas.php on line 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose it's because of this *([quoting](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) the **Instruction separation** section of the manual)* :

> **The closing tag of a block of PHP code
>   automatically implies a semicolon**

This means that your code :

```
<?php
class Foo 
{
?>
<?php
       function bar() {
           print "bar";
       }
}
?>
```

Is the same as :

```
<?php
class Foo 
{;
   function bar() {
       print "bar";
   }
}
?>
```

Which explains the error you get :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION
```

---

**EDIT :** Thinking a bit more about it, I thought that this was strange, considering I often use stuff like this in my templates files :

```
<?php if (...) : ?>
    blah
    blah
<?php endif ; ?>
```

So I tried this :

```
<?php
if (true)
{
?>
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!";
}
?>
```

And it works perfectly fine. OK...

Now, let's try adding the `;`, like `?>` is supposed to do :

```
<?php
if (true)
{;
    echo "Hello, World!";
}
?>
```

This is working fine too, and I get the following output :

```
Hello, World!
```

And, if changing the condition, just to be sure :

```
<?php
if (false)
{;
    echo "Hello, World!";
}
?>
```

Gives no output, and not error.

Considering the sentence I quoted earlier, this is not so surprising... But, still, I'm surprised anyway ^^

Answer (score 2):

`?>...<?` is syntactically a statement, like "echo",  or "return", therefore the first one is the same as

```
<?php
 class Foo 
 {
   echo "";

   function bar() {
       print "bar";
   }
}
```

which is not allowed